# LWUIT - View not getting painted for BB, post closing the app

Tags: blackberry, lwuit

The view is not getting painted in BB device when the following steps are done:

1. First time I run the app, it works fine.
2. Close the application (System.exit(0))
3. Re-open the appllication, the device hangs.

I use the following stuffs in my app:

1. http connection
2. Storage

NOTE: The http request is sent and the response is also received. But the device hangs and view is not getting painted.

Kindly help me in this regard, please.

Comment: Please post some of your code.  Where is it hanging?  Try to do some debugging, to narrow the problem down a little bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) since Oracle ended support for blackberries.